# Define a type alias in Cap'n Proto

Tags: capnproto

I do not understand how one would export a type alias in Cap'n Proto.

The simplest example I can think of is a point cloud. Suppose we have a schema such as

```
struct Point {
    x @0: Float32 = 0;
    y @1: Float32 = 0;
}
```

and then I want to also export a list of those points as a fixed type:

```
struct Point {
    x @0: Float32 = 0;
    y @1: Float32 = 0;
}

using PointCloud = List(Point);
```

It seems to me (based on the generated code) that the `PointCloud` type is not exported as part of the schema. It seems that that `PointCloud` is only usable interally in the schema file.

How can I export this alias so that it is usable externally?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the [roadmap](https://capnproto.org/roadmap.html), and there there is the statement:

> Type aliases: Ability to define a type which is just an alias of some
> other type, and have it show up as e.g. a typedef in languages that
> support that. (The current using keyword is intended only for local
> use and does not affect code generation.)

So perhaps this is the answer to my question... It is simply not currently supported.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, at present type aliases only exist in the Cap'n Proto compiler. They are not exported to code generators.